# Why are my simple donate pages throwing an error?

Tags: civicontribute, simple-donate-form

I am using latest Simple Donate on D7 with Civicrm 4.7.29. I get this error when I go to the contribution page configured for Simple Donate:

Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in CRM_SimpleDonate_Page_SimpleDonationPage->browse() (line 71 of /home/lifechallengesem/public_html/data/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/com.webaccessglobal.simpledonate-2.0/CRM/SimpleDonate/Page/SimpleDonationPage.php).

any help troublshooting would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I had an issue with simple donate throwing errors when I didn't have any payment processor setup. So, do you have one setup?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the extension code it seems to me that the Simple Donate pages are not set properly in settings table. Can you please re-save the Simple donate page setting by navigating to Administer >> CiviContribute >> Simple Donate Configuration ?

Comment: Hmm...not allowing me to save a new configuration. I tried saving a different contribution page and de-slecting the ziptastic function. Tried several different configs. The new configs will not save.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: No error showing in browser. The page just refreshes to "[domain]/civicrm/admin?reset=1". Doesn't give a message about successfully saved.  I'll check logs to see what's there...

Comment: Here's what's in the log: Notice: Constant CIVICRM_MEMCACHE_PREFIX already defined in include_once() (line 359 of [domain]/civicrm.settings.php).

Comment: Are you having N sites installed on same instance having CiviCRM enabled?

Comment: I don't think so. Can you clarify your question? Not sure what you mean. I have a test site on the server. I don't think it would be the same instance of civiCRM. How can I check that?

Comment: I checked the two sites. They have the same site key? Could that be the problem?

Comment: I do not have multi-site enabled. So, no, do not have N sites installed on same instance. Any other thoughts on this? BTW: I have uninstalled and reinstalled Simple Donate several times. No success. What settings tables are associated with Simple Donate?

Comment: Pradeep, can you tell me what is the name of the settings table that controls the Simple Donate configurations?

Comment: civicrm_settings table has all the settings and are stored in serialized format